# How to join all exported results' tables to ONE table with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to add **these tables** into **ONE table** with many rows with **Temporary Table**

[image: Pic]

```
DECLARE @Week int,
    @Year int
SET @Week = 1
SET @Year = 2014
WHILE @Week <= 52 BEGIN
    SELECT  GetTotalPrice.[LocationID],
        SUM(GetTotalPrice.TotalPrice) AS TotalPrice,
        @Week AS WeekNumber
    FROM GetTotalPrice
    SET @Week = @Week + 1
END
```

Comment: Just craete table before `While`, change `Select` to `Insert` and output data after `While`. Thats it.

Comment: @Darka: Could you please give me a clear answer in the "Answer you question" below?

Comment: Your code get the same values for 52 times, changing only the week number, is that what you want?

Comment: @Serpiton: I just would like to merge all tables to one table. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understood your problem right. You have multiple tables which you need to merge into one. If that is true you can do the following changes in your code

```
DECLARE @Locations TABLE
(
LocationID INT,
TotalPrice DECIMAL,
WeekNumber INT
)
DECLARE @Week int,
    @Year int
SET @Week = 1
SET @Year = 2014
WHILE @Week <= 52 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @Locations
    SELECT  GetTotalPrice.[LocationID],
        SUM(GetTotalPrice.TotalPrice) AS TotalPrice,
        @Week AS WeekNumber
    FROM GetTotalPrice
    SET @Week = @Week + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @Locations
```

Comment: That's awesome. Your answer is totally correct to solve my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: @PMay1903: Looping is rarely an optimal solution, though. You might get better suggestions if you showed how `@Week` and `@Year` were used in the query. (My guess is the real query has a WHERE clause that uses those variables for filtering.)

Comment: @AndriyM: I appreciate all your help but in that case that It should be like that...